# Getting index of value in ArrayList

Tags: java, android

```
myHolder.mName.Text = mEmails[position].Name;
```

I have been trying to change this xamarin code into Java and when i make it into

```
 myHolder.mName.getText(mEmails.get(position).getName());
```

I end up getting red line under the text and this gives me alot of time wasted trying to make it work and am still not yet good in java

Comment: Show the exact error message. It's not just a red line.

Comment: And it looks like your first code sets `Text`, whereas your Java code tries to `getText`. Those seem to be opposite of each other.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, thats why i need some help trying to make it work

Comment: But you have yet to post the error you're getting. If you need help, don't make it difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are trying to change "sets" the text and you are doing "get".

Try:

```
myHolder.mName.setText(mEmails.get(position).getName());
```

or if mName is a property (change others to "get" also if they are a property instead of a variable)

```
myHolder.getMName.setText(mEmails.get(position).getName());
```

and if mEmails is a java array:

```
myHolder.mName.setText(mEmails[position].getName());
```